# Storage Write on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, nexus-7

I am developing and android application with emulator of Android Studio 3.6. I am using a virtual device of Nexus 7 with andoird 10.

I have given permission on the manifest file and I have asked for the user to give permission for read write to the external storage.

Although permissions are ok I can not create a folder on the external storage. I attempt to write form a background proccess.

This is the excerpt og manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"   />
```

This is the excerpt of my  Main Activity where I ask the the user to give permission and call the background proccess: UnitDataUpdater

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    // public static String SERVER_API_URL =  "http://local.xxxx.xxxxx.eu/index.php?option=com_alumincocc&view=examlist&Itemid=122&format=json&unitCode=";
    // public static LinearLayout examList;
    public JSONArray uiData;
    ListView examsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        checkPermissions();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String url = "http://xxxxx.xxxxx.eu/index.php?option=com_alumincocc&view=examlist&Itemid=122&format=json&unitCode=478050";
        String result = "";
        examsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.examsList);
        UnitDataUpdater process = new UnitDataUpdater(this);
        try {
            result = process.execute(url).get();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ........



    public void checkPermissions() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super
                .onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,
                        permissions,
                        grantResults);

        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {

            // Checking whether user granted the permission or not.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Showing the toast message
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Write Permission Granted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Write Permission Denied",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the background process where I try to write to the external storage. The method getAppDi is where I am trying to create a new folder. This folder is never created so the rest of the class throws errors.

A strange thing is that at the emulator I don't see the Document folder. I have try the same thing on Downloads folder but still the same.

```
public class UnitDataUpdater extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    //  private static String REMOTE_URL = "http://local.xxxxxx.xxxxx.eu/index.php?option=com_alumincocc&view=examlist&Itemid=122&format=json&unitCode=";
    private String data = "";
    public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private String filePrefix = "i";
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public UnitDataUpdater(Activity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = (MainActivity) mainActivity;
    }

     ........

    private String getAppDir() {
        String externalStoragePublicDirectory = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                .getAbsolutePath();


        String appDirPath = externalStoragePublicDirectory + "/XXXXUnitData";
        File appDir = new File(appDirPath);
        if (!appDir.exists()) {
            if (!appDir.mkdir()) {
                try {
                    throw new Exception("Storage Error");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return appDir.getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you see any error message saying that the permission is not available? Also i think the permission what we grant is applicable only for main process and will not be for the sub processes running under the same app. eg; running under a separate process like (:xyz)

Comment: You are on Android Q?

Comment: @blackapps Yes I om on android Q  on Android Studio Virtual Device

Comment: @TomTaylor No I don't see any errors, at least not in logcat. I don't know where else to look for errors.

Comment: @Christoforos : Can we handle like check if the permission exists or else ask for the user to grant the permission during runtime and then proceed?

Comment: @TomTaylor These are done already but no luck.

Comment: @Christoforos : Can you try the same on the same process as your application runs? Instead of separate process... I believe that shoudl work...

Comment: And basically what's your need for separate process instead of separate thread?

Comment: On Android Q external storage is not readable and writable. Use getExternalFilesDir(null) instead. You do not need any read write permission then in manifest or at runtime.

Comment: @blackapps thanks a lot that solved my problem. Post your comment as answer so I can marked it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android Q external storage is not readable and writable. Use getExternalFilesDir(null) instead. You do not need any read write permission then in manifest or at runtime.